# IE9 text-overflow: ellipsis; not working with text-align: center;

Tags: internet-explorer-9, text-alignment, ellipsis, css

[image: IE9 text-overflow: ellipsis; problem with text-align: center;]

As you can see the first `.` gets over the last `6` and only on `IE9`.

Any workarounds?

**NOTE:**

```
<div class="truncate">666</div>

div { text-align: center; /* NOTE: The text should be on center. */ }
.truncate { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MvaGe/4/

Comment: Can you provide a working jsFiddle example, please? The code you've provided is insufficient to get an ellipsis to show up at all in any browser, so there's clearly some additional code involved here. A working demo will help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: jsFiddle example added.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Hmm.. interesting little glitch. Just for completeness, I've tested it, and it works perfectly in IE8 and IE10, so it's just IE9 that has the problem.

Comment: No problem, yup, only IE9, works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari.

Comment: no progress so far in finding a work around. Sorry. I can report one thing though: the problem goes away if the text is all lower-case (try adding `text-transform:lowercase` in the fiddle). That's hardly a work around, but it may point us in the right direction. I don't have time to keep playing with it now I'm afraid, but I'll check back later to see if there's any more progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `word-wrap: bread-word`, please change it to `word:wrap: normal`. It works for me.